# React JS | using setTimeout prints a number on Page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, settimeout, use-state

I am simply trying to change the heading and content states using React Hooks but I get a number shown on the page, a little google search showed up a bunch of stuff related to how setInterval and Timeout generate a key or value but I have no idea why they're showing up on the page.I can hide it using an empty div but I am curious if I am doing anything wrong, also if I use a class instead of a function the value rapidly increases and my CPU maxes out.

```
 function MyComponent (){
        const [heading, setHeading] = useState('React(Loading)')
        const [content, setContent] = useState('Loading...')
        return(
            <main>
                <h1>{heading}</h1>
                <p>{content}</p>
                {
                    setTimeout(() =>{
                        setHeading('React(Loaded)')
                            setContent('Loaded')
                    }, 2000)} // should change the values, which it does with addition of a number
            </main>
        );
    }
```

The resulting page is that renders is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfzJX.png)
Also on a side note I tried using a onload function to do the same thing but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout returns a number, which is used to identify the timeout when you use clearTimeout. That is why you see the number below the content.

To hide the number, you should move the setTimeout to be outside of the return function. Also, you should use as little JS as possible in the return statement and just use JSX over there, to make the component more clear and readable.

But just moving the setTimeout to be before the return statement is not enough. The function will run on every render, and there are many things that can trigger a re-render - a state change, or a parent re-rendering. So on every re-render, you will set a new timeout. The timeout itself updates a state which triggers a render which triggers the setTimeout - so you are creating an infinite loop.

So you want to call setTimeout only once - you can use useEffect, which will re-run only when the dependency array changes, but if you will leave it empty, it will run only once, because nothing will change and a re-run will never be triggered.

```js
function MyComponent (){
        const [heading, setHeading] = useState('React(Loading)')
        const [content, setContent] = useState('Loading...')

        useEffect((
            setTimeout(() =>{
                setHeading('React(Loaded)')
                setContent('Loaded')
            }, 2000)
        ), []);

        return(
            <main>
                <h1>{heading}</h1>
                <p>{content}</p>
            </main>
        );
}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't knew it returned anything, the above won't work Because it counts as a memory leak and nothing renders, guess I'll use the invisible div, thanks anyways

Comment: What memory leak? Invisible div is not the solution, you shouldn't do it because of the reasons I wrote

Comment: Hey I didn't say it's gonna cause a memory leak, the browser did, it failed to render completely and the last comment was that we should remove all useEffeft occurrences, I didn't pay much attention honestly as the task was to simply change the text content on the page loads

Comment: I am sorry for my earlier behaviour as I was pretty sleep deprived and had to get thr assignment done, the memory leak was allegedly caused by the setTimeout returning a value because it's an arrow function and it returns some value, if we use the useEffect wirh defining the while operation as a seperate function we can get rid of the error and safely render our page, you can see my Answer for the final solution, thanks for giving me a thought

Comment: What you wrote is wrong. For some reason, the component is unmounting before the setTimeout completes. The error you received says that the setState (in your case, setHeading and setContent) are being triggered after the component has been unmounted. You can use cleanup function that will trigger `clearTimeout` when the component unmounts to prevent the callback in the timeout from triggering. You should also check the reason of the unmount, it might be a bug (or not, it depends).

Answer (score -1):

So, by using the above answer we get the following error

`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function`

The reason for this is again the fact that setTimeout returns a number, the final answer is to use the code as a separate function as below:

```
useEffect( timeOutFunction, [])

    function timeOutFunction() {
        setTimeout(() => {
           
                setHeading('React(Loaded)')
                setContent('Loaded'), 2000)
}
```